# NNCの解析結果のグラフの見方について

Tags: ニューラルネットワーク

最近NNCを始めたのですがグラフの見方がいまいち自信ありません。

・青のCOSTとは何を表しているのでしょうか？
・Accuracyの正答率は学習データに対する物で、
　テストデータに対する正答率は出ないのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ご教示ください。

Comment: これはSonyのNeural Network Consoleでしょうか？ https://dl.sony.com/ja/

Comment: はい、そうです。